# Formatting MarkDown Document for PDF

Tags: markdown

I'm learning MarkDown and trying to format a document. When I export to pdf everything runs along one line so it's a really unusable document. Also when I push to git hub the code boxes run on one line and are horizontal scrolling. I tried using enters all through the paragraphs to format however that's super tedious. I'm probably missing something super simple.https://github.com/JamJuiceCreative/JimListerT1A1---Workbook/commit/943304b2635fd7fb077c3af1a3fb3234a594356d?diff=split&short_path=ef9ef14#diff-ef9ef1442330e38856f711db8b1a0f84ff5b9d94b85594ce60a1c30ba207e18f to see my attempts.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is desired. Markdown is just a format to write simple structured contents, and the final style in another format (PDF) is fully controlled by the actual tool you use to convert from Markdown files. You need to edit the question and reveal what exactly is the tool you use for conversion because others cannot guess that out. Besides, such questions (on how to properly use a tool) are more suitable for SuperUser.com.

Comment: I used print to pdf extention on visual studio code.

Comment: "[link to GitHub] to see my attempts"—that's not how Stack Overflow works. Please [edit] a [mre] directly into your question to make it self-contained. See [ask].

Comment: What exactly is the name of that extension? "print to pdf" didn't hit any. Please learn how to ask good questions and then others might be able to help.